# /users and profile pages (/users/...) space the link to the current profile (in the top bar) differently

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

That's what I mean:

[image]

These spaces I emphased - between badges, badges count, and rep are same on all the pages except /users/...

Check yourself: first go to e.g. [home page](http://movies.stackexchange.com) and then to [Users](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users). The spacing I noted changes. Now choose [any user](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/current) in Users. The spacing changes again.

Comment: Related (same issue on another site): https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4917/73791

Answer (score 5):

Wow, you've got good eyes.  Anyway, the bug is because the styles for badge icons on those pages are leaking into the top bar.  Here's a simple CSS rule to fix it:

```
.top-bar .my-profile .-badges .badge1,
.top-bar .my-profile .-badges .badge2,
.top-bar .my-profile .-badges .badge3 {
    margin: 0;
}
```

(I copied that selector from an existing CSS rule that sets a 3px right padding on the badges in the top bar.  Obviously, it would be best to merge this rule into that existing one.)

Answer (score 3):

The issue is in this computed Css rules in `all.css`
`.user-page .badge1, .user-page .badge2, .user-page .badge3`
`margin: 0 2px 0 6px`

Please fix/remove/make it like every other page, which lacks that.

Answer (score 1):

Back at The Workplace we had the same issue (see: [Different layout spacing when on User tab](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4917/73791)), which I noticed and posted a year ago.

However, with the [Rollout of new network site themes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/312365/332286) seems that the bug was "fixed", as now that TWP's [new style](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5706/73791) is live the spacing issue is gone.

I am posting this here, as we seemed to have had the same issue. I suppose that when Movies's new theme is live we should expect this problem to disappear.

Comment: Was my assumption too.