# Movies & TV updated site theme is ready for testing!

Tags: discussion, design

As part of implementing the new unified themes across the network, we're gradually rolling out updated site themes for each site. As of today, we have enabled your updated site theme for testing.

If you can't see it right now, that's by design! This is a very early test implementation of your design and we need your help finding issues with it before we make it live for everyone permanently. So, keep in mind, there will be things that need fixing! We'll address those things as we can.

If you'd like to review it, here's how:

### How do I enable it?

[Click here](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/users/preferences) and check the "Beta test new themes" option. This will turn on the new theme for all sites that have one in testing, including this one. *Here's [more info](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/314542/opt-in-to-beta-testing-new-themes) on how to opt in.* You can uncheck the box to revert to the older theme until the site is live for everyone. **Note, while turning it on is immediate, it will take a few minutes to revert to the old view - *but it will go through!***

### What type of feedback do we need?

#### On this post: Bugs related to this site's design elements

Please help us look for issues/bugs related to the theme design and how we have mapped the old theme to the new. This needs to be done within the [limits of the new unified theme](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/307862/ch-ch-ch-changes-left-nav-responsive-design-themes).

This could include colors of sections of the design or text, problems with JavaScript add-ons (if applicable), the logo or top banner appearance or other artwork.

You can also feel free to ask questions about the new layout if you're unsure how to navigate it.

#### On Meta Stack Exchange: General concerns about left nav or theming

There are some things that are definitely changing everywhere and can't really be adjusted on a per-site basis. A few of them include:

- Top banner is shorter in height, so some artwork has to be adjusted along with some logos.
- Left Navigation is active everywhere (but can be collapsed into a menu by visiting your site preferences - [instructions here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/311237/284336)).
- Responsive layout is active, which lets the site adjust as browser widths change - no side scrolling (some pages haven't been updated, yet, though). For now, if you prefer the scrolling, you can disable this by clicking the "disable responsiveness" link in the footer.
- Many site elements including tags and voting arrows are standardized across the network.
- Link underlining is active. In an effort to make links more visible, they are now being underlined.

If you have concerns or issues regarding the left nav or the overall approach we are taking to theming, then [this Meta Stack Exchange post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/310908/live-left-nav-new-theming-and-responsiveness) is the right place for feedback.

As I mentioned earlier, there are some unique design elements like voting arrows and tags that are being standardized in this process. Keeping these custom elements makes our ability to maintain the sites too complex and, while we're very sad to see them go, we're in a difficult position of needing to make the site designs work together so that we can continue to address feature requests and bugs that will make your Q&A experience better. This is addressed in a [Meta Stack Exchange post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/314799/why-we-initiated-the-latest-round-of-design-changes-and-the-role-of-meta) if you want more detail.

### What new themes?

If you're like, "What the heck are you talking about?", then you should read the Meta Stack Exchange post entitled [Rollout of new network site themes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/312365/rollout-of-new-network-site-themes) (and maybe the posts it links to for the full background). To follow along with the rollout of these new themes, go [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/314979/rollout-of-responsive-design-site-themes-tracking-post).

### Thanks so much for your constructive feedback!

#### Oh, Who am I?

If you don't know me, I'm one of the [Community Managers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99338/who-are-the-community-team-and-what-do-they-do?s=1%7C141.4591) here at Stack Exchange. I'm here to listen to your input and convey it to our Design team for responses and fixes to bugs. I'll do my best to respond to your concerns and explain whether changes we've made are bugs that can be changed or if they're by design and why.

Comment: We need that movie strip back! Can it not be included in the new theme?

Comment: @AJ It is there? I see it.

Comment: @Catija I was looking at mobile version. It is very small.

Comment: @Catija can we even wish for lighter shade of orange in site?

Answer (score 10):

Movie reel is so so so tiny that it's difficult to even understand what is there, compared to before when it used to be the main part of the site design:

Older design:

[image]

Newer design:

[image]

Now it's stressful to identify what is even there and also most movie reel slots are lost now, they used to be [17](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1525/identify-movies-and-tv-shows-from-the-image-in-the-top-bar-banner) of them and now 9.

Even there is space to have all 17 there and potential for little zoom-in and maybe lighter shade of orange will help.

---

**Update:** here is the updated header:

[image]

Personally it looks jumbled-up messy and downright weirdly uncomfortable to look at. We did got movie-reel back on the cost of loosing logo visibility. And most shots are repetitive and the chopped one are looking so bad, even Paulie_D made a way way way better looking version in comment:

[image]

Comment: There seems to be space to include all 17.

Comment: @AJ main issue is it' way tooooooooooooooooo tiny

Comment: There seems to be space for the entire proper top-bar image. Why they thought it would be reasonable to take something *already the same size as the top-bar* and cram it into a tiny space is entirely beyond me.

Comment: Indeed...my version via *Stylish* - https://i.imgur.com/aZZbuSg.png

Comment: @Paulie_D way better

Answer (score 9):

I was quite confident that our site wouldn't be hit too much by the untheming process, primarily because **our old top-bar image *already fit perfectly into the new top-bar***. But...apparently that was just wishful thinking. Given that the new top-bar would perfectly take our existing film strip, the current **miniature image crammed into the right corner seems...less than optimal**.

[image]

I would **implore** the design team to **please** give this a reconsideration. That image is ***the* identifying element** of our site and to have it treated *seemingly* hastily like that is really unfortunate and just makes one feel sad.

I can understand when you have to cut it to the width of the page contents, but even then that's a ton of space to fill. I could also understand when you don't want it under the logo, for which solutions exist, too, like toning the contrast down in that area or making it a little shorter. But really, it **does *not have* to be that tiny**, especially since there is already a **multitude of sites that have a much bigger background image** in the top-bar, one that even extends into the logo in certain conditions.

At the *very least*, I would expect some sound reasoning for *why* it has to be this tiny image that ***deliberately eschews* from using the free space** it has, given how much [consideration went into the original conception](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1501/49) of this design.

---

**UPDATE:** The new version is to me somewhat of an improvement and *might* be a move into the right direction. I do like how the scene images scroll along under the logo when you resize the window, as it adds to the film strip feel. However, there are still some problems with this iteration:

[image]

- The color around the logo as well as the overall colour impression of the whole **top-bar is quite a bit too dark**. That's probably because the *actual* background colour is below the film strip (and partly also because some of the transparency seems to have gone lost in the film strip image), which the logo is a part of now. However, this colour change is quite a **deviation from the site's colour palette** as originally conceived. All in all it makes it a little more drab than the bright orange-red it was originally.
- The logo looks a little crammed into the film strip and lacks some breathing room. This might be helped by **leaving a little bit more room to the sides around the logo**. I think for this a good compromise might be to extend it just far enough so that the left side starts at the content (and symmetrically for the right side). Since the film strip itself is fixated at the left window border, this would avoid the small image fragments left and right of the logo as soon as the window is small enough for the left side-bar to touch the window border, thus producing the best result in the most reliable case (and giving a little more breathing room for the logo in the rest of the cases):

  [image]

Comment: I have to go back to Worldbuilding.SE and the consideration which was given it with the new site design in how the elements pre-transition were incorporated into it post-transition and wonder why M&TV's elements cannot be incorporated as well. The new site design is weaksauce in comparison to the old. I, too, think the reel image is a key design consideration for the site and should be incorporated a lot better than it is in the redo.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 New design was blessing only for worldbuilding. For scifi.se and movies.se we only lost originality we had before.

Answer (score 8):

Are we going to lose colours from our colour scheme too?

Movies & TV colour scheme:

[image]

But we are losing all the blue.

Blue footer is removed and help page sidebar lost it's unique colour sceheme and now it's generic yellow:

Old:

[image]

New:

[image]

Answer (score 8):

The **vote buttons** seem to have been **recoloured** from their intial cyan-blue colour (left) to the site's red-orange (right):

[image] [image]

This removes a little bit of variation from the colour scheme and seems to directly contradict the design for the site's colour scheme as [originally conceived](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1501/49).

I know the buttons can't have a custom shape anymore (and they really didn't before anyway), but they seem to be freely colourable still. Therefore, and given how much consideration went into the original design process, I would *at least* like to hear some sound reasoning for this change in colour scheming. Do those buttons *have* to have the same colour as other buttons?

Answer (score 5):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

Mobile site top bar is design-less:

[image]

Just a shouting plain logo with bright orange/red and without moviereel.

But some other site's are better in this context, like worldbuilding:

[image]

This one is soothing to eye and have site design too.

---

**Update:** it's been resolved I guess?

[image]

But more disappointed :'(

Comment: Plus there is a missing movie reel in the mobile view.

Comment: Plus: you're running out of battery, too much use of SE network :D

Comment: @OldPadawan iPhone batteries are shit

Comment: We've got a slightly different header design going live in the next build.

Answer (score 5):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

The new ask button in the upper right corner of an individual question page seems to cause rather odd intra-word breaks in the question title, for example on [this question](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/94030/49):

[image]

Comment: [Related bug over on SO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/376921/4631427). It appears to be a new one.

Answer (score 4):

Well, for something positive, it seems the design unification fixed [this long-standing bug](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1652/49). So that's something.

Comment: Regarding your tag edit: technically, it's only [meta-tag:status-completed] if one is opted in to seeing the new design.

Comment: @Randal'Thor I leaned myself out of the window a little in assuming this will carry over into the production version (and SE staff tends to `status-completed`-tag things that will be fixed "soon in the next build", too).

Answer (score 4):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

[tools](https://movies.stackexchange.com/tools) page new tag section is broken:

[image]

It's crossing the margin line:

[image]

Comment: I feel like a lot of less often used tool pages are less than bug free in the new responsive design. For example the Community Events moderator page has broken layout, too. The entire responsive design of SE seems to be largely in beta testing still.

Comment: As @NapoleonWilson points out, a number of pages are not yet fully responsive. However this is certainly a strange looking bug that I don't think was there before. I'm adding it to our list.

Comment: @JonEricson any update on this one?

Answer (score 3):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

Copyright text colour is so light:

[image]

That's it's hard to read but previously it was more readable:

[image]

side by side:

[image][image]

Comment: This is fixed and will go live in the next build.

Comment: @AaronShekey website looks better but meta is same

Answer (score 3):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign) The vertical line has appeared [yet again](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/314844/357396).

When we disable left navigation bar, this line appears on the left and right sides everywhere.

> [image: line in the badge section]

On the home page

> [image: Line on the home page]
>
> [image: On the recently active questions]

Comment: The line is intentional on all sites where the question background and the page background are close in color. It helps separate the sections of the page.

Answer (score 2):

I'll be honest, I wasn't at all broken up by the movie reel being shrunk down and moved to the side. But the way it's been put back is terrible. First, it cuts off *Citizen Kane* which is considered by many to be the best movie ever made. I'd think we'd want to keep that one visible. Second, it appears to repeat, but doesn't. It looks like it was chopped up into overlapping pieces and reassembled haphazardly. Is there a reason it was done this way?

Comment: Yeah current version made me regret even complaining about previous header. I am devastated.